# Reformatting non-sequential Item ids in two different Pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have two databases, a user ratings database of movies that looks like this:

```
    userID  movieID  rating   timestamp
0        1       9      2.5  1260759144
1        1       7      3.0  1260759179
2        1       1      3.0  1260759182
3        2      13      2.0  1260759185
4        2       1      4.0  1260759205
5        3       6      2.0  1260759151
6        3      11      2.0  1260759187
7        3       4      2.0  1260759148
8        3       3      3.5  1260759125
9        4       2      2.0  1260759131
```

and a movieID to movie name database that looks like this:

```
    movieID                                  title
0         1                       Toy Story (1995)
1         2                         Jumanji (1995)
2         3                Grumpier Old Men (1995)
3         4               Waiting to Exhale (1995)
4         6     Father of the Bride Part II (1995)
5         7                            Heat (1995)
6         9                         Sabrina (1995)
7         10                   Tom and Huck (1995)
8         11                   Sudden Death (1995)
9         13                      GoldenEye (1995)
```

The problem is that the movieID in the second database is not in sequential order (Numbers 5, 8, and 12 are missing). I need them  to be in order for a lookup later in the program. Is there a way to reformat the ids in sequential order, and change the corresponding movieID in the ratings database so I can look up the movie later?

Comment: In your example, there is no overlap. How one would figure out, which ids to change, if there are no names. Also, for the look up, you do not necessarily have to have them in order.

Comment: `I need them to be in order for a lookup later in the program.` Is "the program" still in Pandas, or some external dependency? If Pandas, as @harvpan mentions, it's not a requirement.

Comment: I have reformatted the example to have overlap. Due to the way I have structured my program, they do need to be in sequential order with no missing values. i.e[1,2,3,4] instead of [1,3,4,5] @harvpan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a sequential ID field:

```
movie_DB['new_movie_id'] = range(len(movie_DB))
```

Then, create a dict from old ID to new ID:

```
id_dict = dict(zip(movie_DB['movieID'], move_DB['new_movie_ID']))
```

Map the movie ID in the user rating database:

```
user_DB['new_movie_id'] = user_DB['movieID'].map(id_dict)
```